# Applescript for creating a Mail.app account with outgoing server goes wrong - multiply hidden copies

Tags: macos, email, applescript

Lets do basic using Applescript.
I try to create a Mail Account. (In the past I did get something working but nowadays it doesn't work.)

If I create an Account I do get an ID in the console back, but it never shows up in Mail.app. Why??? I did read something about ghosted accounts and servers.
If I check the list of accounts using the code the Account is there.
Running the create a Account code again, I got two of that account ( for every run there is one and the same account added ). Why???
When I quit Mail and restart Mail they are no more.
Also last point why isn't a smtp server created?

Finaly I did put all those code snippets togather to see what goes wrong; but honestly "I don't know"

But it I use code to delete the existing account first ( Ghost Account ) I get a error ( See Image )
[image]

What goes wrong, is it my code or a bug in Applescript or Mail.app?

```
set accountName to "ipadawan@stackunderflow.web"
set accountUser to accountName
set accountServer to "imap.mailhosted.nl"
set accountPort to 993 --995 
set accountSSL to true
set accountType to "imap"
set fullName to accountName
set emailAddress to accountName
set deleteMail to false -- do not quote

set myPassword to "mypassword"

-- Optional SMTP account details - not always easy to add later:
set smtpUser to accountName
set smtpServer to "smtp.mailhosted.nl"
set smtpPort to 465
set smtpSSL to "YES"
set useAuthentication to "YES"
set smtpAuth to "PASSWORD"

set stopScript to false
tell application "Mail"
    activate
    delay 5
    (* get and show all the accounts *)
    set accntList to ""
    repeat with anAccount in every account
        set accntList to accntList & "All accounts -- Name: " & name of anAccount & "
" & "User name: " & user name of anAccount & "
" & "Type: " & account type of anAccount & "
" & "Email addresses: " & email addresses of anAccount & "
        
"
    end repeat
    display alert accntList
    
    
    (* check if the new account exists *)
    if account accountName exists then
        display dialog "Account '" & accountName & "' already exists. Delete them and stop" buttons {"Stop script"} with icon stop
        set stopScript to true
        
        repeat with anAccount in every account
            set accntList to ""
            if name of anAccount is accountName then
                set accntList to "Existing account -- Name: " & name of anAccount & "
" & "User name: " & user name of anAccount & "
" & "Type: " & account type of anAccount & "
" & "Email addresses: " & email addresses of anAccount
                (* show and delete *)
                display alert accntList
                delete anAccount
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        
        
    end if
    if stopScript is false then
        try
            display alert "Try to create an Account for : " & accountName
            set newacct to make new imap account with properties {name:accountName, user name:accountName, password:myPassword, uses ssl:true, server name:accountServer, port:accountPort, full name:accountName, email addresses:{accountName}}
            
            set accntList to ""
            set accntList to "New Account -- Name: " & name of newacct & "
" & "User name: " & user name of newacct & "
" & "Type: " & account type of newacct & "
" & "Email addresses: " & email addresses of newacct
            (* show new account *)
            display alert accntList
            
            (* Create a new SMTP server in the list. *)
            set addsmtp to make new smtp server with properties {server name:"xxx.mycompany.com", user name:"xxx@mycompany.com", uses ssl:true, authentication:password, password:""}
            set smtp server of newacct to addsmtp
            
        end try
    end if
    
end tell
```

BTW, It does do the same thing for a pop mail account.
Is someone see my issue's and able  to help me out? I really appreciate that. Thank you